# handling string length in javafaker

Tags: java

i am using javafaker dependency to generate random Usernames for testing my application.But in my application the first name field doesn't accept names with less than 3 characters.Sometimes the names generated from java faker is less than 3 chars and validation message is thrown.So i want to generate names with string length greater than or equal to 3.

Maven Dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Code

```
Faker faker = new Faker();
System.out.println(faker.name().firstName());
```

Comment: how about using the the fullName() ?

Comment: @Aleson thanks for the suggestion.Actually I tried it before.It can eliminate string length issue.But in my application i have to send First name and last name separately and if i use fullname() it won't look proper as an user will have 4 name strings.Is there any way to handle the length of the string that is genearted that u know of? TIA.

Comment: generate them in a while. Keep generating new ones, unless they are long enough

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```java
final Faker faker = new Faker();
String userName = faker.name().firstName();
final Set<String> usernames = new HashSet<>();
while (set.size() < len && userName.length() >= size) {
      usernames.add(userName);
      userName = faker.name().firstName();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a check for the length of the generated name and regenerate it if it is tripped. Check below code snippet.

```
Faker faker = new Faker();
String name = faker.name().firstName();
while (name.length() <= 3) {
    name = faker.name().firstName();
}
```